# Chrome not centering text

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I am getting a weird issue in chrome on my GS3 and Nexus 7. When I view my site in Portrait mode and switch to landscape my intro text doesn't center in the screen. Very strange. But it I refresh in landscape mode and go portrait if works fine going back and forth.

Here is the test site: http://www.brianmworks.com

Here is the CodePen: http://codepen.io/Budha210/pen/JkxbE

I have tested on my phone in the default samsung browser, dolphin and opera. It looks perfect in those. This is only occurring in Chrome.

Comment: Portrait: <img src="http://i1231.photobucket.com/albums/ee520/budha210satx/77c73dd1-3555-4ff4-88d0-a21cdddf3774_zpsee6468b8.jpg"/> Landscape:<img src="http://i1231.photobucket.com/albums/ee520/budha210satx/745c3f31-ac5d-4320-a85d-5328ad10b0b1_zpscef6ac05.jpg"/>

Comment: I'm having difficulty posting images. Will continue to work on posting them.

Answer (score 0):

h1 is a block level element.. try putting text-align:center in its class